# JavaScript in HTML changing background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no idea what I am doing. I thought I had everything going well with html, then I had to add some simple javascript.
I am just trying to change the background color when the user clicks a button.

This is what I have so far:

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Javascript

```
function changeBackground() {
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'grey')
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
    else
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    }
}
```

Html

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">
    Click Me!
</button>
```

Comment: terrible code styling and terrible code design...

Comment: Make sure you insert 4 spaces before any code you put in your post.

Comment: Thanks ketan, I didn't know how to use this site. First time using it.

Comment: Works fine in chrome. You should use proper html structure for the code...code added below!

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/5m21q0rn/

Comment: @Richard you welcome and please take care of next time. You have `=` operator wrong. Use `==`. Check the answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was just one small thing messing it all up. First time using this site, will come back if I ever need more help. Hopefully, I won't be such a novice next time. :D

Comment: @Mehmet - what a useless comment. Needlessly patronising and not constructive at all. It's obvious the OP is just starting out, have some patience. Your questions are far from perfect too, I've read a few of them.

Comment: How do I show this questioned as answered? Just accept someone and that's it? It's fine JayMee. You are both correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard, I'll offer an alternative to all of the other answers - and you should consider the following structure in all web front-end that you develop.

HTML is **what** you display, JS is how it **behaves**, CSS is how it is **styled**.

That said, try to avoid styling elements with JS but rather toggle a class and allow CSS to do the work. In your case, you could write:

```
function changeBackground()
{
   $(body).toggleClass('dark');
}

<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">
   Click Me!
</button>

body
{
   background-color: grey;
}

body.dark
{
   background-color: black;
}
```

Here, we're simply toggling a class on and off the body element, the CSS will 'respond' accordingly. We have a nice clear separation of concerns.

You may choose your class name to make more sense than `dark`, but the idea is your JS doesn't care about colors and details of styling.

Comment: For the benefit of beginners, this answer does the right thing. As it is implemented, it requires jQuery (which the question did not).

Comment: @JohannesJander - it's tagged with `jQuery`

Comment: I understand, @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, I wanted to note it explicitly for beginners. The question is on a very basic level, so the answers should provide a lot of handholding, imo.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` clause is wrong (you are assigning instead of testing the background color):

```
function changeBackground() {
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == 'grey'){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0zmjavtt/),

The problem is you are using `assignment operator =` instead of `comparison operator == or ===`

```
function changeBackground() {

  if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == 'grey') {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
  }
}
```

Hope this works for you